# add delay inside settimeout angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using settimeout to run some code after a specific delay. However I want to add additional delay inside the settimeout block between two lines of code. I tried by using delay() but it is not working. How can I do this? Thanks in advance for your help?

My code:

```
setTimeout(() => {
      this.messageService.add({
        severity: 'success', summary: 'Yay',
        detail: 'Successfully done'
      });
      console.log('here1');
      delay(1000);
      console.log('here2'); // run this after delay


    }, 1500);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
      this.messageService.add({
        severity: 'success', summary: 'Yay',
        detail: 'Successfully done'
      });
      console.log('here1');
      
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('here2'); // run this after delay
      }, 1500);


    }, 1500);
```